# Unit testing a PUT method of the Django REST framework

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write tests for `APIviewSet`. GET and POST work fine, but I can not combine tests for the PUT method. I think that the problem has to do with the path I pass to the function, but I can not figure out how to fix it. I found nothing in the documentation.

```
class ResponseTracebackTestCase(TestCase):
"""class for traceback"""


class JustTest(ResponseTracebackTestCase):

    maxDiff = None

    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs access to the request factory.
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.time = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='admin', email='admin@admin.com', password='top_secret1', born_date=self.time, date_joined=self.time)
        self.view = ClientViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post': 'create', 'put': 'update'})

    #...some_code

    def test_admin_update(self):
        request = self.factory.put('/api/service/client/', {...some_data})
        force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
        response = self.view(request, pk=1)
        self.assertResponseCodeEquals(response, 200)
        response.render()
        self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content), {...some_data})
```

Traceback:

```
  File "/code/service/tests.py", line 138, in test_admin_update
    self.assertResponseCodeEquals(response, 200)
  File "/code/service/tests.py", line 32, in assertResponseCodeEquals
    ) + '\n' + ''.join(format_list(response._init_stack))
AssertionError: 404 != 200 : Response code was '404', expected '200'
```

response.detail:

```
{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Not found.', code='not_found')}
```

Comment: Put applies on a "detail" viewset, not a "list" viewset which your seems to be using (no way to identify the associated resource from the url)

Comment: I try to change address to ./client/4/ like detal view in browser, but it not work.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this case, I write a unit test and have to same a problem when testing for reverser `user-detail` because I register the router with viewset, so I don't know how to solve this problem!